# Rufus stops copying files from the ISO

Tags: release-freya

I'm still at the stage of trying to create a boot USB drive. Rufus hangs at extracting: `F:\pool\main\g\gcc-4.8\cpp-4.8_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04_amd64.deb` (4.4 MB) for some reason.

I will try to get some blank DVDs tomorrow and maybe try Roxio instead to create a boot DVD instead of a USB drive, if this will work?

Thanks John

Comment: Download the ISO again

Comment: Did you check the MD5 checksum of the file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this : https://etcher.io/
It is multiplatform and it is as easy as clicking a button:
[image: Etcher screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes something like this happens. The best thing to do is redownload the iso and try again. Also check to make sure you have enough space for the iso on your USB drive, I've overlooked this before.

If you still have a problem, try a different USB installer.

Some popular ones are

- unetbootin
- rufus
- Universal USB Installer
- Linux Live USB Creator

Answer (score -2):

Try the program `imagewriter`. Use this command to install: `sudo apt install usb-imagewriter`.

Comment: The OP is trying to create a bootable elementary drive within Windows. This answer is not applicable.